# Is there an option to remove the "administrative" messages from a whatsapp chat?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm in a whatsapp group chat that has a fairly large amount of messages, as well as a lot of traffic (people joining and leaving the chat). To help me keep only the messages I actually need I delete all the unneeded messages, but then I get a situation where I have pages on pages filled with administrative messages about people leaving and joining. Is there a way to delete those messages to clear up the chat?

[image: screenshot of only messages about people leaving and joining]

<sup>The screen shot is from the web app, but I use it primarily on Android devices.</sup>

Comment: This question was asked on superuser at first, where it is off-topic, so I deleted it there, and posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's an option to adjust the types of notifications under in app settings or general settings for that app then nothing I can think of. If there is another way I doubt it will be worth the hassle.